# how to set Navigator label formatter in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I need to set the Navigator x axis Labels formatter but doesnt work ?is there anyway to set the x axis label values for Navigator?

Please see the code below

```
   navigator: {
        handles: {
            backgroundColor: 'white',
            borderColor: 'red',
        },
        labels: {
            align: 'center',
            x: 3,
            y: 16,
            formatter: function () {
                if (((this.value * 4) % 1000) == 0) {
                    if ((((this.value) * 4) / 1000) % 5 == 0) {
                        alert("inside");
                        return (((this.value) * 4) / 1000) + "s";
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("inside else");
                        return (((this.value) * 4) / 1000) + "s";
                    }

                }
                else {
                    return (((this.value) * 4) / 1000) + "s";
                }
            }
        },
        enabled: true,
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `labels` options should be nested in an `xAxis` option:

```
   navigator: {
        handles: {
            backgroundColor: 'white',
            borderColor: 'red'
        },
        xAxis: { // you are missing this level
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    if (((this.value * 4) % 1000) == 0) {
                        if ((((this.value) * 4) / 1000) % 5 == 0) {
                            alert("inside");
                            return (((this.value) * 4) / 1000) + "s";
                        }
                        else {
                            alert("inside else");
                            return (((this.value) * 4) / 1000) + "s";
                        }

                    }
                    else {
                        return (((this.value) * 4) / 1000) + "s";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Mark , thanks for your reply .i had already added labels in x axis but the value in navigator is calculated based on the xaxis but i want to change the value in navigator .is there anyway to change?

Comment: You can prepare your own serie for navigator and use by parameter http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#navigator.series the you achive separeted series on global xAxis and navigator.